# dagre layout draw all nodes in same position when using cy.add

Tags: javascript, ajax, tree, cytoscape.js

fist of all, let me explain my problem:
I'm using cytoscape to draw a network based on information located in a MySQL database, using Ajax the information is passed from a PHP document to the script, if I use a layout like "circle" everything goes fine, but I need to draw the tree to be readable so I've decided to use "dagre" this is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"dispositivos.php",
        async: true,
        success:  function(datos){
            var dataJson = eval(datos);
            dibujanodos(dataJson);
          },
        error: function (obj, error, objError){
            //avisar que ocurrió un error
        }

});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"relaciones.php",
    async: true,
    success:  function(datosdos){
        var dataJsondos = eval(datosdos);
        dibujarlineas(dataJsondos);
      },
    error: function (obj, error, objError){
        //avisar que ocurrió un error
    }

});

var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  layout: {
    name: 'dagre'
  },

  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-opacity': 0.5,
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'right',
        'background-color': '#11479e'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 4,
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'line-color': '#9dbaea',
        'target-arrow-color': '#9dbaea'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [

      //for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(datos).length; i++) {
        //      data: { id: datos[i].sn,
          //            etiqueta: "IP: " + datos[i].ip_adress + " Device id: " + datos[i].device_id}
          //    }

        { data: { id: 'n15' } },
        { data: { id: 'n14' } },
        { data: { id: 'n13' } },
        { data: { id: 'n12' } },
        { data: { id: 'n11' } },
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
      { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } },
      { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n3' } },
      { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n5' } },
      { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n6' } },
      { data: { source: 'n6', target: 'n7' } },
      { data: { source: 'n6', target: 'n8' } },
      { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n9' } },
      { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n10' } },
      { data: { source: 'n11', target: 'n12' } },
      { data: { source: 'n12', target: 'n13' } },
      { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n14' } },
      { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n15' } },
    ]
  },
});

function dibujanodos(datos){

 for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(datos).length; i++) {
     cy.add({
         data: { id: datos[i].sn,}
       });
   }
}


function dibujarlineas (datosdos){

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(datosdos).length; i++) {
  var source = datosdos[i].Device_SN_O;
cy.add({
  data: {
      id: datosdos[i].Device_SN_O + datosdos[i].Device_SN_D,
      source: source,
      target: datosdos[i].Device_SN_D,
      etiquetaedge: datosdos[i].Port_ID,
  }
});
}
}
```

In this code, I left some manually added nodes in order to show the problem as you can see it, in the image below nodes created with cy.add function are all in the same position while manually added nodes are ok.

[displayed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRXm8.png)

Even though all edges and nodes' id are correct, it doesn't look like a tree, once I expand the nodes it looks like this:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ia4f.png)

I would like to get this result since the graph is drawn, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the new nodes, run the layout again

```
var layout = cy.makeLayout({ name: 'dagre' });
layout.run();
```